# Azure DevOps Advance Security Scanning cannot read pnpm lock file

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to add the `AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1` task to a pipeline to onboard onto the advanced security feature of ADO. My repository holds a TypeScript Node.js application that uses `pnpm` to manage packages. When I run the build and the dependency scanning task runs, I get this error:

```
##[error] Failed to read pnpm yaml file /home/vsts/work/1/s/pnpm-lock.yaml
(Line: 12, Col: 5, Idx: 195) - (Line: 12, Col: 5, Idx: 195): Exception during deserialization
```

The first 15 lines of my `pnpm-lock.yaml` file look like this:

```yaml
lockfileVersion: '6.0'

settings:
  autoInstallPeers: true
  excludeLinksFromLockfile: false

overrides:
  axios@>=0.8.1 <1.6.0: '>=1.6.0'

dependencies:
  '@apple/app-store-server-library':
    specifier: 0.1.1
    version: 0.1.1
  '@fastify/helmet':
    specifier: 11.1.1
    version: 11.1.1
...
```

I ran the whole file through a YAML validator and it is in fact valid YAML. Line 12 looks wholy correct. The task then fails to properly detect my repo's dependencies.

I am expecting the ADO advanced security features to work with `pnpm` as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/security/github-advanced-security-dependency-scanning?view=azure-devops#supported-package-ecosystems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pnpm-lock.yaml` is currently not supported, but `package-lock.json` is. I modified my pipeline to be the following:

```yaml
steps:
- template: azure/pipelines/build-steps.yml
- script: rm pnpm-lock.yaml
  displayName: Remove PNPM lock file
- script: npm i --package-lock-only
  displayName: Generate NPM lock file
- task: AdvancedSecurity-Dependency-Scanning@1
```

After this modifications, my NPM dependencies were detected. I think this solution is better than asking developers to remember to run both `pnpm i` and `npm i` when modifying dependencies.

I suppose there is a risk that the pipeline restores a different package than the developer's machine if the package sources aren't kept in sync. But until ADO supports both `pnpm-lock.yaml` and `package-lock.json`, that risk will always exist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation ([**Supported package ecosystems**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/security/github-advanced-security-dependency-scanning?view=azure-devops#supported-package-ecosystems)), the **`pnpm-lock.yaml`** is not a directly supported lockfile format on Advanced Security Dependency scanning.

---

As a workaround, you can try to convert the lockfile from **`pnpm-lock.yaml`** to **`package-lock.json`** which is supported by the Dependency scanning.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If support for `pnpm-lock.yaml` is not planned, could you please update the documentation to tell customers that they need to use `package-lock.json` even if they are using `pnpm`?